# How to show indicators in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Carousel should contain indicators showing current slide and allowing to select slide by clicking in indicator.
Slides should change after 5 seconds.
According to Bootstrasp 3 carousel documentation it should support this.
Actually, indicators are not show.

I tried code from bootstrap manual:

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
        </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/124">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/124" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/123">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/123" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/105">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/105" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/95">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/95" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/107">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/107" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/100">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/100" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/98">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/98" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/78">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/78" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">

                <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/11">
                    <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/11" />
                </a>
            </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

But indicators are not displayed.
How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `.carousel-indicators` into `.carousel-inner`.

UPD: Ok.. try this:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/124">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/124" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/123">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/123" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/105">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/105" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/95">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/95" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/107">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/107" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/100">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/100" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/98">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/98" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/78">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/78" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">

        <a href="/store/Webconte/Details/11">
            <img src="/store/Webconte/Image/11" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I moved ol element inside `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">` . I tried also to wrap ol element into separate `<div class="carousel-inner">` element. In both cases indicators are still not visible. How to fix ?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Why bootstrap official tutorial in getbootstrap.com recommends to add them before ?

Comment: @Andrus It's your mistake. Carousel must be in a separate block, but your `#carousel-example-generic` also contains `.category-list` and `.bottomcategories`. So, you could move them out of `#carousel-example-generic` or move `.carousel-indicators` to `.carousel-inner`. I don't know how your styles constructed, so I've suggested a quick version :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the indicators are showing. Set:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: black;
}
```

And you can see them at bottom of page.

**EDIT:**

Try with this, and look for them at bottom of page:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    background-color: black;
}
```